# How does Google auth 2.0 app redirect work?

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, google-signin

I have a initial screen to let the user sign in with their google account and once they authenticate, I want to redirect to another html page. How could I do this? In my developer console, I defined the redirect uris as http://localhost:8080/test.html to redirect. but once I log in successfully, nothing happens? Anything else I need to do?

Comment: there is a pretty complete oauth2 official guide by google.

Answer (score 1):

the developer console does not create redirections, it whitelists redirections that YOUR CODE will point (so as to avoid malicious hijacking by third parties who attempt to impersonate you).

you need to customize your signin `redirect_uri` parameter as defined in [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)